# document.getElementById() doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript

I have 20 unique random numbers and check between 6 unique numbers.
the first check works, but after refreshing the 6 unique numbers,  of the numbers return undefined.
I've given the full code so people can tinker with it.
no need for CSS, that is just to identify different numbers.

sorry for the long codes, it's just how i keep my code tidy.

```js
var num = [];
var com = [];
var s = 0;
var j = 0;

function twenty() {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    com[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49) + 1;
    var x = com.length;
    x = x - 1;
    for (y = 0; y < x; y++) {
      var t1 = com[y];
      var t2 = com[i]
      while (t1 == t2) {
        com[x] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49) + 1;
        t1 = com[x];
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
      document.getElementsByClassName(t)[i].innerHTML = com[s];
      s++;
    }
  }
}

function calc() {
  num = [];
  var out = "";
  var z = document.getElementById('max').value;
  for (i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    num[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49) + 1;
    var x = num.length;
    x = x - 1;
    for (y = 0; y < x; y++) {
      var t1 = num[y];
      var t2 = num[i]
      while (t1 == t2) {
        num[x] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49) + 1;
        t1 = num[x];
      }
    }
    out += num[i] + ", ";
  }
  document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = out;
}

function check() {
  s = 0;
  if (j == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
        var set = 0;
        var test1 = document.getElementsByClassName(t)[i].innerHTML;
        var y = num.length;
        for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
          var comp = num[x];
          if (test1 == comp) {
            set = 1;
          }
          if (set == 1) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(t)[i].innerHTML = "<input type='button' value = '" + com[s] + "' id='" + s + "' class='yes' >";
          } else if (test1 == undefined) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(t)[i].innerHTML = "undefined";
          } else {
            document.getElementsByClassName(t)[i].innerHTML = "<input type='button' value = '" + com[s] + "' id='" + s + "' class='no' >";
          }

        }
        s++;
      }
    }
    j = 1;
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
        var set = 0;
        var test1 = document.getElementById(s).value;
        var y = num.length;
        for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
          var comp = num[x];
          if (test1 == comp) {
            set = 1;
          }
          if (set == 1) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(t)[i].innerHTML = "<input type='button' value = '" + com[s] + "' id='" + s + "' class='yes' >";
          } else if (test1 == undefined) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(t)[i].innerHTML = "undefined";
          } else {
            document.getElementsByClassName(t)[i].innerHTML = "<input type='button' value = '" + com[s] + "' id='" + s + "' class='no' >";
          }
        }
        s++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html{

}
input[type=button].yes{
 background: green;
 border: none;
}
input[type=button].no{
 background: red;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src='code.js'></script>
</head>

<body onload='twenty()'>
  <h1>lottery randomizer</h1>
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <td>randomize numbers
      </td>
      <td>choose number of random numbers
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='button' onclick='calc()' value='randomize'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='number' value='6' id='max'>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        your numbers are:
        <div id='num'>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border='1' class='table'>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='0' id='1'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='0' id='2'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='0' id='3'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='0' id='4'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='0' id='5'>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='1' id='1'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='1' id='2'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='1' id='3'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='1' id='4'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='1' id='5'>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='2'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='2'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='2'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='2'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='2'>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='3' id='1'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='3' id='2'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='3' id='3'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='3' id='4'>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='3' id='5'>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type='button' onclick='check()' value='check numbers'>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `id` should be **unique** in a document - you've reused id's 1,2,3,4,5 twice (i.e. you have 3 of each) if you `getElementById('1')` how does the code *know which want you want*? hint: it gives you the first one every time

Comment: for all that, I use document.getElementsByClassId(x)[y]; the table is updated through the javascript

Comment: but your question states `document.getElmentById() doesn't work properly` - so ... does it or not?

Comment: sorry, i figured out that the div id's were messing with the code, however, it doesn't make sense since #4 worked perfectly

Comment: In general when you have come to the conclusion that some browser API "does not work properly", it's time to lean back and wonder how likely it is that you've discovered such a problem.